# ¿Diferencias entre un redirect 302 y uno 307?

Tags: http, redirección

¿Qué diferencia hay entre un `redirect 302` y un `redirect 307`?

[La especificación W3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) parece indicar que ambos se usan para redireccionamientos temporales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la versión 1.0 de HTTP, sólo existía el `302` con el significado de "la petición que acabas de hacer debes volver a hacerla en esta otra URL". Implícitamente se entendía que debías usar el mismo verbo HTTP. Por tanto, si hacías un `GET uri` y recibías un `302`, a continuación debías hacer otra vez `GET` con la nueva URI. En este sentido equivaldría al moderno 307.

Pero sin embargo, y contradiciendo el uso esperado, se comenzó a poner de moda el uso de 302 como respuesta a un envío de formulario. Así, si una página contenía un formulario HTML, y el usuario tras rellenarlo pulsaba el botón "Enviar", típicamente el navegador hacía una petición `POST` a la URI especificada en el formulario. El servidor podría simplemente procesar los datos del formulario y retornar un `200 Ok`, junto con una página de resultados, pero esto causaba un efecto indeseado, y es que si el usuario "recargaba" la página de resultados, se volvería a hacer el POST, volviendo a enviar el formulario y con el riesgo de una operación no idempotente.

Para evitar esto se convirtió en costumbre responder a ese POST con un  `302`, de modo que el navegador a continuación haría un `GET` a esa nueva URL que mostraría la página de resultados. Así, una recarga de esa página haría un nuevo `GET` en lugar de repetir el `POST`.

Así pues, el código `302` se había vuelto ambiguo. O bien tenía su significado previsto originalmente de que el recurso se había movido temporalmente y había que repetir el verbo sobre la nueva URL, o bien el nuevo significado adoptado "de facto" de que la respuesta 302 a un POST debería implicar el uso de un GET para obtener la página de resultados.

Para deshacer esa ambigüedad, la versión 1.1 de HTTP introdujo dos nuevos códigos de estado:

- `303`: Este sería el significado "haz un GET a esta URI" tras haber hecho antes un POST.
- `307`: Este sería el significado original del `302`: "repite el mismo verbo sobre esta otra URI".

Por cierto que en HTTP/1.1 no debería usarse ya 302, que ha sido reemplazado por 303/307 como acabo de explicar. Pero aún hay sitios que siguen usándolo en respuesta a un POST.